# C# Menu Component

Tags: c#-4.0, user-interface, components

I am looking for a pointer in the right direction, rather than a full solution to my question.

Below is an example of the kind of user interface, taken from Microsoft Excel, that I'm wanting to produce for my program.

- A list of items
- Styled (Different when hovering)
- Clickable
- Able to add an icon or image to each row

[image: Example]

How would I go about building an interface, which unser interface component would I start with, and then populate with data.

When developing for windows phone 7, I would usually use a 'stackpanel', which isn't available from C# in a windows form application.

Comment: Any preference for WPF or WinForms? You wrote "windows form" but I'm not sure you referred to the UI technology...

updating your question with the right tag will get you the attention of the "appropriate" Stack Overflow crowd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be much easier if you use [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) than with WinForms - it is also quite similar to Silverlight used for WP7, so you could reuse your experience (it has StackPanel, among othe things :) ).

What you want would be very hard with Win Forms, but actually very simple with WPF - it is just a styled ListBox, with very simple DataTemplate - something you can do after first few chapters of any book or tutorial.

[This](http://www.wpftutorial.net/) should get you started.

Comment: Perfect.  I didn't even know that the WPF existed.  I've got the XAML code editor and it's much more familiar.  Thank you!

Comment: Minor comment, probably it should be a styled `Menu` element, not `ListBox`

Comment: @Snowbear It depends, Menu gives you the "popup" infrastructure, but it is not clear whether OP wants it (IMO the fact that he wanted to use StackPanel suggests the opposite).